# "The API response was an error" in OpenFDA search query

Tags: openfda

I used the following query:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20120101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code:LLZ+AND+product_problem_flag:Y+AND+event_type:"Death"&limit=1

OpenFDA returned a message "The API response was an error. Bummer. Check the syntax and give it another try."

I then tried to relax the time frame and made the query to be:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20010101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code:LLZ+AND+product_problem_flag:Y+AND+event_type:"Death"&limit=1

It returned 1 result.

Could anyone help diagnose whether there is a bug in my query? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a bug in the openFDA interface. I would report it. I tried changing the start date to 2002 and up'ed the limit to 2. I found there is only 1 entry for Feb. 23, 2005. If I change the year to 2006 (past the only entry), then you have the problem. It should return a JSON response with 0 entries.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the query, using an ordinary web browser:

`https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20120101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code:LLZ+AND+product_problem_flag:Y+AND+event_type:"Death"&limit=1`

The API returns:

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "No matches found!"
  }
}`

I believe the message the original poster was seeing is on the interactive query explorer on the openFDA website. It manually reprocesses no-results queries into the "bummer" error message. I'll log a bug to handle "no results found" cases.

In this case, neither the API nor the query are wrong. There are no results for the time period specified.

Comment: Hum, we I did the same on IE browser I got a 404 page not found.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this query on a web browser and it returned the same message you posted. What I did originally was on the interactive query explorer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I used Firefox not IE. IE did give me 404 page not found.